# JSON array not displaying correctly in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

I have the following JSON data that's returned from an endpoint via a fetch() call:

```
[{"username":"\"Hyh\"","name":"GitHub","url_main":"https://www.github.com/","url_user":"","exists":"Illegal","http_status":"","response_time_s":"0.1234"},{"username":"\"Hyh\"","name":"GitLab","url_main":"https://gitlab.com/","url_user":"https://gitlab.com/\"Hyh\"","exists":"Available","http_status":"200","response_time_s":"0.14287607499954902"}]
```

I'm trying to display it like so:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  FlatList,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";

const Results = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { owner } = route.params;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(
      "https://endpoint.com/search?user=" + JSON.stringify(owner.text)
    );
    const data = await resp.json();
    setData(JSON.stringify(data));
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const Item = ({ url }) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{url}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item url={item.url_main} />;

  return (
    <View>
      {loading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator style={styles.loader} size="large" color="#7a16e4" />
      ) : (
        <SafeAreaView>
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.response_time_s}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Any idea why nothing is rendering on my screen? I tried replacing my JSON with the JSON data here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist and it worked. I've confirmed data returns from the fetch through console.log(data).

Answer (score 0):

```
setData(JSON.stringify(data));
```

you convert the object to string and pass it to the `data` prop in FlatList which is not correct.
the `data` prop should be an array

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#required-data

Your code should look like this

```
setData(data);
```

Comment: This is not my issue. I've edited the main post. It's the same result either way.

Comment: Try  console.log(typeof(data)) and see if it return `string` or `object`

Comment: It returns an object, but JSON.stringify makes it a string.

Comment: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {username, name, url_main, url_user, exists, http_status, response_time_s}. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead" is the error I get with the new solution.

Comment: This problem is related to the `renderItem` function try to console.log(item) and see what you get